# Question about Ethernaut Telephone question. Creating attack method instead of using constructor

Tags: constructor, attacks

[image]This is entire contract for the ethernaut Telephone question. I created attack() function, but a youtuber suggests constructor(). Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

It's not important. A contracts constructor is ran at deployment time, so it would save one transaction (everything happens on deployment instead of you having to deploy then call the attack() function) but that's the only point.